# Creating a function signature that removes null from a union type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am just starting to convert all my code to work with strictNullChecks. I want to have a function that does the following:

```
function defaultValue<TUnionNull>(value: TUnionNull, default: TWithoutNull): TWithoutNUll{
    return value == null ? default : value
}

function requiresNotNullString(): void

var name: string | null;

var checkedName: string = defaultValue(name, "Fred");
```

In other words if the input of the function is `string | null` I want the return type to be `string`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
function defaultValue<T>(value: T | null, defaultValue: T): T {
    return value == null ? defaultValue : value
}
```

(changed it to `defaultValue` because `default` can't be used)

([example in playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0A%0Afunction%20getUnionString(input%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%20%7C%20undefined)%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%20%7C%20undefined%7B%0A%09return%20input%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20toDefault%3CT%3E(value%3A%20T%20%7C%20undefined%20%7C%20null%2C%20defaultValue%3A%20T)%3A%20T%7B%0A%09return%20value%20%3D%3D%20null%20%3F%20defaultValue%20%3A%20value%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20possibleString%20%3D%20getUnionString(null)%3B%0A%0Avar%20definiteString%20%3D%20toDefault(possibleString%2C%20%22defaultString%22)%3B) provided by @Roaders)

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much identical to what I had just come up with. It does work but requires that you pass a type to the function: `defaultValue<string>(value,default)` It would be nice if the `<string>` was not required

Comment: No, it doesn't, the compiler infers `T` based on what you pass as `value`. I checked your code and it compiled just fine

Comment: if `value` is `string | null` then return type will be `string | null` so `var return: string = defaultValue(` will fail as a null might be returned.

Comment: Are you using different code than you posted? Because I'm trying it and I get no compilation errors.

Comment: Yes you're correct. A more complicated of this wasn't working in my actual code in my project but your solution does actually work as illustrated in the playground (link added to answer)